# Azure blob storage - uploading very slow

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the trial account in the azure blob storage. I try to upload 100000 generated files from my local machine. The operation already have duration over 17 hours and uploaded only ~77000 files.
All files created by a simple bash-script:

```
for i in {1..100000}
do
    echo $i
    echo $i > $1\\$i.txt
done
```

Code for the uploading:

```
using(var stream = File.OpenWrite(textBoxManyUploadFileName.Text))
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(textBoxManyUploadFrom.Text)) {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        storage.StoreFile(file, id, ((FileType)comboBoxManyUploadTypes.SelectedItem).Number);
        writer.WriteLine("{0}={1}", id, file);
    }
}

public void StoreFile(Stream stream, Guid id, string container) {
    try {
        var blob = GetBlob(id, container);
        blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
    } catch(StorageException exception) {
        throw TranslateException(exception, id, container);
    }
}

public void StoreFile(string filename, Guid id, int type = 0) {
    using(var stream = File.OpenRead(filename)) {
        StoreFile(stream, id, type);
    }
}

CloudBlob GetBlob(Guid id, string containerName) {
    var container = azureBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    if(container.CreateIfNotExist()) {
        container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container
        });
    }
    return container.GetBlobReference(id.ToString());
}
```

The first 10000 files have bean uploaded by 20-30 minutes then the speed decreased.
I think it may due to the fact that the file names are GUID and Azure tries to build the clustered index.
How to speed up? What is the problem?

Comment: `GetFiles` returns strings, right? But `StoreFile` takes a stream... what am I missing? (I'm wondering where you dispose of the stream. Perhaps something is leaking.) You might want to just do `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { container.GetBlobReference(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).UploadText(i.ToString()); }` to simplify what you're measuring.

Comment: I do not think that memleaks or disposing affect to the uploading speed. Stream is created by calling File.OpenRead(filename)

Comment: And are those streams properly disposed?

Comment: Based on your answer above, are you creating stream from the file variable in the following line of code:

storage.StoreFile(file, id, ((FileType)comboBoxManyUploadTypes.SelectedItem).Number);

This line is actually

storage.StoreFile(File.OpenRead(file), id, ((FileType)comboBoxManyUploadTypes.SelectedItem).Number);

and not 

storage.StoreFile(stream, id, ((FileType)comboBoxManyUploadTypes.SelectedItem).Number);

in your code. Correct?

Comment: @brainstream And now your code appears to pass an integer as the container name. It's hard to debug something as subtle as a resource leak (best guess) if you don't share the actual code you're using. All we can do is make guesses.

Comment: @smarx An integer is the legacy from old project. It translated to string in the high level wrapper. PS my problem is solved by using the parallel uploading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload many small files, you should use multiple threads.
You can use [BeginUploadFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.beginuploadfromstream) or [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) for instance.

Comment: Why the first 10000 files have been uploaded fast?

Comment: Use a profiler to find the bottleneck. It might be your log : writer.WriteLine("{0}={1}", id, file);
Also are you using the latest SDK ?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried use the local file saving and they have been writen in ~20 minutes. So, problem not in my code. Yes, i'm using the latest SDK.

Comment: I ran my test application on two machines and got double speed. Parallel uploading must help me for end task. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One more thing I noticed in your code is that you're calling GetBlob() function in your StoreFile() function which in turn calls CreateIfNotExist() function on your blob container. Please note that this function also result in a call to Storage Service thus adding delay in your upload process (not to mention you're also charged for a storage transaction each time you call this function).

I would recommend that you call this function just once before starting your blob upload.

Comment: For first 10000 files CreateIfNotExist() not played any roles.